# How to train multiple stacked neural networks alternatively? (Keras)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

Suppose I'm defining four neural network models with their own loss functions.
The input of the next neural network is dependent on the output of the previous network.

```
Model1 -> Model2 -> Model3 -> Model4
```

For simplicity, let the four neural networks be shown below:

```
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import numpy as np

x = np.random.rand(300,10)
y = np.random.rand(300,1)

# Model 1
inputs1 = keras.Input(shape=(10))
x1 = layers.Dense(1, activation='relu')(inputs1)
model1 = keras.Model(inputs=inputs1, outputs=x1)
model1.compile(loss="mean_squared_error")

# Model 2
inputs2 = keras.Input(shape=(1))
x2 = layers.Dense(1, activation='relu')(inputs2)
model2 = keras.Model(inputs=inputs2, outputs=x2)
model2.compile(loss="mean_squared_error")

# Model 3
inputs3 = keras.Input(shape=(1))
x3 = layers.Dense(1, activation='relu')(inputs3)
model3 = keras.Model(inputs=inputs3, outputs=x3)
model3.compile(loss="mean_squared_error")

# Model 4
inputs4 = keras.Input(shape=(1)
x4 = layers.Dense(1, activation='relu')(inputs4)
model4 = keras.Model(inputs=inputs4, outputs=x4)
model4.compile(loss="mean_squared_error")
```

I would like to stack and train these models, training each model at a time while keeping the weights frozen in the remainder networks.

So in one training iteration, Model1 would be trained then the output would be passed to Model2. Model2 would be trained and then the output passed to Model3 and so forth and then another epoch would be started.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not consider models 1,2,3,4 as consecutive layers and build a single model?

Comment: In reality the models are much more complex and are for different tasks. The models described above is just for simplicity so the question would be clear.

Comment: Please consider an upvote to the accepted answer. That would highly be appreciated. Thanks -)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your query, there are two requirements:

> 1. The output of one model would be the input of the subsequent model
> 2. Train each model at a time with concern `loss` and `metrics` etc.

Below is the schematic diagram of what we need to achieve. Let's consider we have `3` models (`x`, `y`, and `z`) where the first model's output would be the input for the next model and go on. Each of these `3` models is also self trainable. In our demonstration, we will be working with an Image dataset (`mnist`).

[image]

---

Let's try to achieve this.

---

1. We will demonstrate one way to achieve this but hopefully, there **should be a much more convenient way**. We will use the `MNIST` data set and **3 models** for example, `model_1`, `model_2`, and `model_3`. Though these models will individually train on `MNIST`'s `x_train` and `y_train (softmax)`, but we will get the **proper feature maps** from `model_1` and set it as input for `model_2` and so on.

```
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow import keras
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
```

```
# Model 1
def model_1(input = (28,28,1)):
    inputs_1 = keras.Input(shape=(input), name="img1")
    x = layers.Conv2D(16, 3, activation="relu", name='conv1_model1')(inputs_1)
    x = layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation="relu", name='conv2_model1')(x)
    x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(name='gap1')(x)
    x = layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax', name='pred_1')(x)
    return keras.Model(inputs=inputs_1, outputs=x, name='model_1')

# Model 2
def model_2(input):
    inputs_2 = keras.Input(shape=(input), name='img2')
    x = layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation="relu", name='conv1_model2')(inputs_2)
    x = layers.Conv2D(16, 3, activation="relu", name='conv2_model2')(x)
    x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(name='gap2')(x)
    x = layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax', name='pred_2')(x)
    return keras.Model(inputs=inputs_2, outputs=x, name='model_2')

# Model 3
def model_3(input):
    inputs_2 = keras.Input(shape=(input), name='img3')
    x = layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation="relu", name='conv1_model3')(inputs_2)
    x = layers.Conv2D(16, 3, activation="relu", name='conv2_model3')(x)
    x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(name='gap3')(x)
    x = layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax', name='pred_3')(x)
    return keras.Model(inputs=inputs_2, outputs=x, name='model_3')
```

Now, we will call `model_1` and take one **appropriate feature map** and pass it to `model_2` as its input and so for the `model_3`.

```
x = model_1()
y = model_2(x.get_layer('conv2_model1').output_shape[1:]) # feat_map: (24, 24, 32)
z = model_3(y.get_layer('conv2_model2').output_shape[1:]) # feat_map: (20, 20, 16)

print(x.get_layer('conv2_model1').output_shape[1:])
print(y.get_layer('conv2_model2').output_shape[1:])
print(x.output_shape, y.output_shape, z.output_shape)
# (24, 24, 32)
# (20, 20, 16)
# (None, 10) (None, 10) (None, 10)
```

2. Now we will train each model (`x`, `y`, and `z`) at a time. But before that here is something that needs to understand about what we've done so far. We build model `x` and its input would be (as we mentioned before) `28 x 28 x 1`. And model `y`, its input is the output feature maps of layer `conv2_model1` which comes from model `x`. In `tf. keras` we can do that in the following way:

```
# ---------- Data part ------------
# Let's first grab the data
(x_train, y_train), (_, _) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
x_train = tf.expand_dims(x_train, -1)
x_train = tf.divide(x_train, 255)
y_train = tf.one_hot(y_train , depth=10) 

data_x, data_y = x_train[:10], y_train[:10]
print(data_x.shape, data_y.shape)
# (10, 28, 28, 1) (10, 10)
```

```
# ---------- Modeling part ------------
x.summary()
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
img1 (InputLayer)            [(None, 28, 28, 1)]       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1_model1 (Conv2D)        (None, 26, 26, 16)        160       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2_model1 (Conv2D)        (None, 24, 24, 32)        4640      
_________________________________________________________________
gap1 (GlobalAveragePooling2D (None, 32)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
pred_1 (Dense)               (None, 10)                330       
=================================================================
# model x compiling and calling fit method on it 
x.compile(
    loss = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
    metrics = ['accuracy'],
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam())
x.fit(data_x, data_y, epochs=1)
# 5ms/step - loss: 2.2842 - accuracy: 0.2000

# now, we need output feature maps of layer `conv2_model1` from model `x`
# to do that, we first build a model that will give output of such model. 
# however, this was also possible to build mulit-output `x` model that 
# would give (None, 10) and output of this layer (`conv2_model1`).
pred_x_model = tf.keras.Model(x.input, x.get_layer('conv2_model1').output)

# next we pass input (data_x) to these pred_x_model 
# to get the feature maps of layer `conv2_model1`
pred_x = pred_x_model(data_x)
print(pred_x.shape)
# (10, 24, 24, 32)
```

As we can see how we've achieved the output feature maps of model `x`, especially its layer `conv2_model1` `(24, 24, 32)`. Now, we can use these feature maps as an input to the next model, which is model `y`.  And also after training model `y`, we can get another feature map for another next model, in our case which is model `z`.

```
y.summary()
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
img2 (InputLayer)            [(None, 24, 24, 32)]      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1_model2 (Conv2D)        (None, 22, 22, 32)        9248      
_________________________________________________________________
conv2_model2 (Conv2D)        (None, 20, 20, 16)        4624      
_________________________________________________________________
gap2 (GlobalAveragePooling2D (None, 16)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
pred_2 (Dense)               (None, 10)                170       
=================================================================

# calling model y and 
# using `pred_x` for input as it should be now for model `y`
y.compile(
    loss = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
    metrics = ['accuracy'],
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam())
y.fit(pred_x, data_y, epochs=1)
# 8ms/step - loss: 2.0186 - accuracy: 0.3000

# grab the proper feature maps from model `y`'s layer (`conv2_model2`) which 
# would be the input for model `z`.
pred_y_model = tf.keras.Model(y.input, y.get_layer('conv2_model2').output)

pred_y = pred_y_model(pred_x)
print(pred_y.shape)
# (10, 20, 20, 16)
```

So, we have `pred_y`, a feature map of size `(20, 20, 16)` and ready to set as input for model `z`.

```
z.summary()
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
img3 (InputLayer)            [(None, 20, 20, 16)]      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1_model3 (Conv2D)        (None, 18, 18, 32)        4640      
_________________________________________________________________
conv2_model3 (Conv2D)        (None, 16, 16, 16)        4624      
_________________________________________________________________
gap3 (GlobalAveragePooling2D (None, 16)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
pred_3 (Dense)               (None, 10)                170       
=================================================================

# calling model z 
# set `pred_y` as its input
z.compile(
    loss = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
    metrics = ['accuracy'],
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam())
z.fit(pred_y, data_y, epochs=1)
# 5ms/step - loss: 1.9422 - accuracy: 0.3000

# as we have 3 models, our model cycling end here.
# we take the output from model z's last softmax layer
pred_z = z(pred_y)
print(pred_z.shape)
# (10, 10)
```

That's it.